# vb.net List of dynamic type

Tags: vb.net, list, generics, dynamic, types

I'm building a MVC structure for a part of my program.

I've done the Models of 5-10 tables and what they have in common is only the constructor. (which takes the recordset.fields)

Here's my function to fill these objects:

```
Public Function reqTable(ByVal pTable As String, ByVal pType As Type, ByVal pNoProjet As Integer, Optional ByVal strAdditionnalConditions As String = "") As List(Of Object)
    Dim lstRetour As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)

    rsRequestCSV = conSQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & pTable & " WHERE NoProjet = " & pNoProjet & " " & strAdditionnalConditions)
    With rsRequestCSV
        While Not .EOF
            lstRetour.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(pType, New Object() {rsRequestCSV.Fields})) 'New clsTable(rsRequestCSV.Fields))
            .MoveNext()
        End While
    End With
    Return lstRetour
End Function
```

What I'm not able to achieve is to return a List(Of pType) instead of List(Of Object).

The reason I want this is to have headers in my datagridviews even if they're empty.

So is there a way to return a List(Of MyModel'sType) ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: `Dim x As T = New T()` can (and should) be shortened to `Dim x As New T()`.

Comment: Well, I'm an ex Java coder, I'll keep this in mind thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `As pType` instead of `As Object` (but consider using a conventional type argument name, i.e. `T` instead of `pType`), remove the now obsolete `pType` argument, and use the following to create and add the instances:

```
Public Function ReqTable(Of T)(ByVal table As String, ByVal noProject As Integer, Optional ByVal additionalConditions As String = "") As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New List(Of T)()

    ' Where is this declared?! It probably should be declared here.
    request = conSQL.Execute( _
        String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE NoProjet = {1} {2}", _
                      table, noProjet, additionnalConditions))

    While Not request.EOF
        result.Add( _
            CType(Activator.CreateInstance( _
                    GetType(T), New Object() {request.Fields}), _
                T))
        request.MoveNext()
    End While

    Return result
End Function
```

`GetTpe(T)` gets you a `System.Type` instance representing the type argument. Since VB, unlike Java, has [reified generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1927789/1968) you can thus create instances from type argument.

Apart from that, pay attention that .NET has different code style conventions than Java; for instance, all methods should use PascalCase, not camelCase. And like in Java, use of Hungarian notation is discouraged. Use concise but descriptive names. And, as Rene noted, your code suffers from an SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the SQL injection issue ect try this:

```
Public Function reqTable(of T)(ByVal pTable As String, ByVal pNoProjet As Integer, Optional ByVal strAdditionnalConditions As String = "") As List(Of T)
    Dim lstRetour As New List(Of T)

    rsRequestCSV = conSQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & pTable & " WHERE NoProjet = " & pNoProjet & " " & strAdditionnalConditions)
    With rsRequestCSV
        While Not .EOF
            lstRetour.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(T, New Object() {rsRequestCSV.Fields})) 'New clsTable(rsRequestCSV.Fields))
            .MoveNext()
        End While
    End With
    Return lstRetour
End Function
```

Comment: +1, but you might need to cast `Activator.CreateInstance`s return value to `T` first (if you are using Option Strict, which you should).

Comment: Thank Heinzi your 100% correct, I edited this in browser so missed that one. (edit, looks like you cant pass prams when using of T? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx)

Comment: Well this Function works, 
but now I got some problems with the BindingSource thing...

But that's an other thing... But if you want to feel free to say why it shouldn't work, because it seems quite Ok for me.