# Spring 4 generic class, get the parametrized type

Tags: java, spring, generics

Hi have a Generic class in Spring, and I would like to get the generic T type class for an injected bean. I know the [classic way in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) and read [how Spring 4 implements Java Generics](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics). Also, I tried to find a solution using [ResolvableType](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html) but nothing works.

```
@Autowired
GenericDao<SpecificClass> specificdao;
```

---

```
public GenericDaoImpl <T> {

    private Class<T> type;

    public DaoImpl () { 
         this.type = ...? 
    }

    public T findById(Serializable id) {
        return (T) HibernateUtil.findById(type, id);
    }
}
```

Are there any way to avoid this?

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier
GenericDao<SpecificClass> specificdao;
```

---

```
@Repository("specificdao")
public SpecificDaoImpl extends GenericDao<SpecificClass> {
      public SpecificDaoImpl () {
          // assuming the constructor is implemented in GenericDao
          super(this.getClass())
      }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I doubt if this can be easily done (due to type erasure). BTW: from the code you've provided, it seems you're trying to re-implement the functionality provided by the Spring Data. Why not to use it instead?

Comment: Yes it is, but I would to do it by my own. Thanks.

Comment: One small remark: The result `this.getClass()` would be the same if called from the super class `GenericDaoImpl`, since `getClass()` returns the runtime type. So the class object doesn't need to be a parameter of the `GenericDaoImpl` constructor, `GenericDaoImpl` can call it itself.

Comment: Also: You don't need the unchecked cast in `findById` since you have the class object. You can use `return this.type.cast(HibernateUtil.findById(type, id));`, which is a little more safe since it will actually check that the result is of the right type.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18709327/452775) seems to contain info about almost the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question: what you want to achieve is very tricky.

You can use [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) and then do something like:

```
import net.jodah.typetools.TypeResolver;

public GenericDaoImpl <T> {

    private Class<T> type;

    public GenericDaoImpl () { 
         Class<?>[] typeArguments = TypeResolver.resolveRawArguments(GenericDaoImpl.class, getClass());
         this.type = (Class<T>) typeArguments[0];
    }

    public T findById(Serializable id) {
        return (T) HibernateUtil.findById(type, id);
    }
}
```

**But still I doubt if it's a good idea**. Because usually you don't want:

```
@Autowired
GenericDao<SpecificClass> specificDao;
```

But instead:

```
@Autowired
SpecificDao specificDao;
```

Why? Because each DAO has almost always completely different methods than other DAOs. The only generic methods, common to all, are probably: `findById`, `findAll`, `save`, `count`, `delete` etc.

So subclassing from a GenericDAO is the most obvious way, as it allows you to add any needed method inside a concrete DAO.

BTW: You said that you want re-implement Spring Data functionality on your own.  But please notice that in Spring way, you still have to create concrete repositories.