# Catching a generic exception

Tags: java, generics, exception, functional-programming

## Problem

I am writing a `Result` type in Java, and I have found a need for it to have a method that performs an operation which may fail, and then encapulates the value or exception in a new Result object.

I had hoped this would work:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingSupplier<R, E extends Throwable>
{
  R get() throws E;
}

public class Result<E extends Throwable, V>
{
  ...
  public static <E extends Throwable, V> Result<E, V> of(ThrowingSupplier<V, E> v)
  {
    try
    {
      return value(v.get());
    }
    catch(E e)
    {
      return error(e);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

But Java cannot catch an exception defined by a type parameter.
I have also tried using `instanceof`, but that also cannot be used for generics. Is there any way I can implement this method?

## Definitions

This is my result type before the addition of the `of` method. It's intended to be similar to both [Haskell's `Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either) and [rust's `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/), while also having a meaningful [`bind` operation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-):

```
public class Result<E extends Throwable, V>
{
  private Either<E, V> value;

  private Result(Either<E, V> value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public <T> T match(Function<? super E, ? extends T> ef, Function<? super V, ? extends T> vf)
  {
    return value.match(ef, vf);
  }

  public void match(Consumer<? super E> ef, Consumer<? super V> vf)
  {
    value.match(ef, vf);
  }

  /**
   * Mirror of haskell's Monadic (>>=)
   */
  public <T> Result<E, T> bind(Function<? super V, Result<? extends E, ? extends T>> f)
  {
    return match(
        (E e) -> cast(error(e)),
        (V v) -> cast(f.apply(v))
    );
  }

  /**
   * Mirror of Haskell's Monadic (>>) or Applicative (*>)
   */
  public <T> Result<E, T> then(Supplier<Result<? extends E, ? extends T>> f)
  {
    return bind((__) -> f.get());
  }

  /**
   * Mirror of haskell's Applicative (<*)
   */
  public Result<E, V> peek(Function<? super V, Result<? extends E, ?>> f)
  {
    return bind(v -> f.apply(v).then(() -> value(v)));
  }

  public <T> Result<E, T> map(Function<? super V, ? extends T> f)
  {
    return match(
        (E e) -> error(e),
        (V v) -> value(f.apply(v))
    );
  }

  public static <E extends Throwable, V> Result<E, V> error(E e)
  {
    return new Result<>(Either.left(e));
  }

  public static <E extends Throwable, V> Result<E, V> value(V v)
  {
    return new Result<>(Either.right(v));
  }

  /**
   * If the result is a value, return it.
   * If it is an exception, throw it.
   *
   * @return the contained value
   * @throws E the contained exception
   */
  public V get() throws E
  {
    boolean has = match(
        e -> false,
        v -> true
    );
    if (has)
    {
      return value.fromRight(null);
    }
    else
    {
      throw value.fromLeft(null);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Upcast the Result's type parameters
   */
  private static <E extends Throwable, V> Result<E, V> cast(Result<? extends E, ? extends V> r)
  {
    return r.match(
        (E e) -> error(e),
        (V v) -> value(v)
    );
  }
}
```

And the `Either` type, designed to closely mirror [Haskell's `Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either):

```
/**
 * A container for a disjunction of two possible types
 * By convention, the Left constructor is used to hold an error value and the Right constructor is used to hold a correct value
 * @param <L> The left alternative type
 * @param <R> The right alternative type
 */
public abstract class Either<L, R>
{
  public abstract <T> T match(Function<? super L, ? extends T> lf, Function<? super R, ? extends T> rf);

  public abstract void match(Consumer<? super L> lf, Consumer<? super R> rf);

  public <A, B> Either<A, B> bimap(Function<? super L, ? extends A> lf, Function<? super R, ? extends B> rf)
  {
    return match(
        (L l) -> left(lf.apply(l)),
        (R r) -> right(rf.apply(r))
    );
  }

  public L fromLeft(L left)
  {
    return match(
        (L l) -> l,
        (R r) -> left
    );
  }

  public R fromRight(R right)
  {
    return match(
        (L l) -> right,
        (R r) -> r
    );
  }

  public static <L, R> Either<L, R> left(L value)
  {
    return new Left<>(value);
  }

  public static <L, R> Either<L, R> right(R value)
  {
    return new Right<>(value);
  }

  private static <L, R> Either<L, R> cast(Either<? extends L, ? extends R> either)
  {
    return either.match(
        (L l) -> left(l),
        (R r) -> right(r)
    );
  }

  static class Left<L, R> extends Either<L, R>
  {
    final L value;

    Left(L value)
    {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T match(Function<? super L, ? extends T> lf, Function<? super R, ? extends T> rf)
    {
      return lf.apply(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void match(Consumer<? super L> lf, Consumer<? super R> rf)
    {
      lf.accept(value);
    }
  }

  static class Right<L, R> extends Either<L, R>
  {
    final R value;

    Right(R value)
    {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T match(Function<? super L, ? extends T> lf, Function<? super R, ? extends T> rf)
    {
      return rf.apply(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void match(Consumer<? super L> lf, Consumer<? super R> rf)
    {
      rf.accept(value);
    }
  }
}
```

### Example Usage

The main use of this is to convert exception-throwing operations into monadic ones. This allows for (checked) exception-throwing methods to be used in streams and other functional contexts, and also allows for pattern matching and binding on the return type.

```
private static void writeFiles(List<String> filenames, String content)
{
  filenames.stream()
      .map(
          (String s) -> Result.of(
              () -> new FileWriter(s) //Open file for writing
          ).peek(
              (FileWriter f) -> Result.of(
                  () -> f.write(content) //Write file contents
              )
          ).peek(
              (FileWriter f) -> Result.of(
                  () -> f.close()) //Close file
          )
      ).forEach(
          r -> r.match(
              (IOException e) -> System.out.println("exception writing to file: " + e), //Log exception
              (FileWriter f) -> System.out.println("successfully written to file '" + f + "'") //Log success
          )
      );

}
```

Comment: Could you paste all code necessary to run your example ? I find it hard to reason with code without running it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the optimistic assumption that the interface fulfills the contract, as ordinary Java code will always do (enforced by the compiler). If someone bypasses this exception-checking, it’s not your responsibility to fix that:

```
public static <E extends Exception, V> Result<E, V> of(ThrowingSupplier<V, E> v) {
    try {
        return value(v.get());
    }
    catch(RuntimeException|Error x) {
        throw x; // unchecked throwables
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") E e = (E)ex;
        return error(e);
    }
}
```

Note that even the Java programming language agrees that it is okay to proceed with this assumption, e.g.

```
public static <E extends Exception, V> Result<E, V> of(ThrowingSupplier<V, E> v) throws E {
    try {
        return value(v.get());
    }
    catch(RuntimeException|Error x) {
        throw x; // unchecked throwables
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw ex; // can only be E
    }
}
```

is valid Java code, as under normal circumstances, the `get` method can only throw `E` or unchecked throwables, so it is valid to rethrow `ex` here, when `throws E` has been declared. We only have to circumvent a deficiency of the Java language when we want to construct a `Result` parameterized with `E`.

Comment: Ooh, that would work!
Though, we don't need to catch `Error`, as it wouldn't be caught by the `Exception` catch further down.

Comment: @ZoeyHewll indeed, it would work without it, but I think it’s clearer when handling all unchecked throwables explicitly. It has the advantage that it continues to work, if you ever decide to change `<E extends Exception>` to `<E extends Throwable>`.

Comment: I just realised a single case where this would fail, is if `E` is itself a `RuntimeException`. Though this class wouldn't really be useful in that context anyway, there seems to be no way to impose that restriction (and I'm not sure I'd want to).

Comment: I suppose, that’s the reason why types like `Future` do not even try to declare a type variable for the exceptional case; the throwable type hierarchy is not the best design, to say it politely…

Answer (score 2):

You need access to the class of the exception and then use some generics in the catch block.

One simple way is to pass the `Class<E>` class to the `Result.of` method:

```
public static <E extends Throwable, V> Result<E, V> of(
        ThrowingSupplier<V, E> v,
        Class<E> errorType) {

    try {
        return value(v.get());
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        if (errorType.isInstance(e)) {
            return error(errorType.cast(e));
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // rethrow as runtime?
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Result.of(() -> new FileWriter(s), IOException.class)
```

[`Class.isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) is the dynamic equivalent of the `instanceof` static operator, while [`Class.cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) is the same as statically casting: `(E) e`, except that we don't get a warning from the compiler.

---

**EDIT:** You need to think what to do when the catched `Throwable` is not of the type of the exception you are expecting. I've wrapped it in a `RuntimeException` and have rethrown it. This allows to keep using a fluent style for your monad, but is not transparent any more, as now any exception is wrapped in an unchecked exception. Maybe you could add a 3rd argument to `Result.of` to handle this specific case...

Comment: Given that the only checked exception type that `e` could be is the type `E`, would it be sensible to assume `e` is a kind of `RuntimeException` if it's not `E`, and simply rethrow it (maybe after a cast)?

Comment: @ZoeyHewll No, `e` can also be an `Error`, which is a non recoverable error condition, such as `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: @ZoeyHewll But catching `Exception` instead of `Throwable` would help here. Catching `Throwable` is not a good practice anyway. W.r.t. assuming that if it's not the checked exception you expect, then it's a `RuntimeException`, I think that it would be too optimistic. There are methods that throw more than one checked exception, i.e. `Class.newInstance`

Comment: The type of `ThrowingSupplier` prevents it from throwing any checked exception other than the one specified

Comment: @ZoeyHewll I think you are correct, I was thinking about a hierarchy of checked exceptions, but the signature of the closure would take care of it.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having the class as a method parameter? It feels like unnecessary redundancy with the type parameter

Comment: @ZoeyHewll Without explicitly passing the class of the exception as an argument, I know of another way, but it's more complex. You need an abstract superclass with the generic type parameters, and in the immediate subclass, you could get the `Class<E>` of a generic type parameter `E`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18708282/1876620) for how to do it, but you'd need to make your `Result` class extend some abstract class that declares the generic type params. Or maybe create a dedicated subclass of `Result` with the sole purpose of extracting the `Class<E>`...

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** this seems not to work at all. I'm keeping it here for now because I've linked to is elsewhere, and because it uses a method provided in other accepted answers, which I would like to continue to investigate.

---

Using [Federico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602749/6112457) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18708282/6112457) linked in the comment, I have deduced a solution with the same method signature as the original problem, and I have created a class which encapsulates this functionality for future use.

The `Result` implementation:

```
public class Result<E extends Exception, V>
{
  ...
  public static <E extends Exception, V> Result<E, V> of(ThrowingSupplier<V, E> v)
  {
    try
    {
      return value(v.get());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Class<E> errType = Reflector.getType();
      if (errType.isInstance(e))
      {
        return error(errType.cast(e));
      }
      else
      {
        throw (RuntimeException) e;
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And the `Reflector`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

/**
 * This class only exists to provide a generic superclass to {@link Reflector}
 * @param <E> The type for the subclass to inspect
 */
abstract class Reflected<E>
{ }

/**
 * This class provides the ability to obtain information about its generic type parameter.
 * @param <E> The type to inspect
 * @author
 */
@Deprecated
public class Reflector<E> extends Reflected<E>
{
  /**
   * Returns the class corresponding to the type {@code <E>}.
   * @param <E> The type to inspect
   * @return The class corresponding to the type {@code <E>}
   */
  public static <E> Class<E> getType()
  {
    return new Reflector<E>().getParameterType();
  }

  private Reflector() {}
  private Class<E> getParameterType()
  {
    final ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    return (Class<E>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that the elements of `ParameterizedType::getActualTypeArguments` are not always able to be cast to a `Class`. On a different machine, I am receiving a `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl`, which is a `Type` but cannot cast to `Class`.